# xamarin intent extension with netstandard cause MT2001 error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, intents-extension

I'm trying to add siri intent to my application.
I've created intent extensions project, than created ios library project (kit project as in a documentation) which has reference to .netstandard project with shared logic (core).

The core project use MvvmCross and when i'm trying to build main application it cause to:

> error MT2001: Could not link assemblies. Reason: Error while
>   processing references of 'Diabetto.iOS.Intents, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

With more detailed logs i've known a reason of this error:

> Error while processing references of 'Diabetto.iOS.Intents' --->
>   Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly:
>   'MvvmCross, Version=6.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   ---> Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'MvvmCross, Version=6.4.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'

I've tried to add nuget reference to iOS class library, to iOS intent library (unsuccessful, got error

> Failed to add reference. The package 'MvvmCross' tried to add a
>   framework reference to 'System.Drawing.Common.dll' which was not found
>   in the GAC

VS 2019 16.3.5, iOS project 13.1

To be clear, my project structure

[image: projectstructure]

and [link to project](https://github.com/l1pton17/Diabetto)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem.
Explicit add nuget reference to System.Drawing.Common and MvvmCross.
Problem was in System.Drawing.Common, VS is trying to use GAC version. With nuget reference it use .net standard version.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT only after 2 days after posting answer :C